# How to format columns of an existing spreadsheet from the command line on Mac

Tags: command-line, export-to-excel, xlsx, libreoffice-calc

I need to format columns in a spreadsheet generated from `CSV` using this format on the command line on a Mac:

```
_([$NAD] * #,##0.00_);_([$NAD] * (#,##0.00);_([$NAD] * "-"??_);_(@_)
```

In case you wonder, the Namibian Revenue Service requires this format and if I can generate the spreadsheet it'll save time to upload the data which I now have to do manually every month even though the `CSV` is generated semi-automagically from the book keeping software's backend.

Preferably `XLSX` because I use [QSV](https://github.com/jqnatividad/qsv/) (or rather its `TO XLSX` command, but `ODS` will of course also work because conversion is easy and they are working on something like `TO ODS`.

Language Preference in descending order: `Perl`, `LUA`, `Python`, `Any` (working on the Mac/Homebrew).

I can write the `bash` function to tie this together if the script can accept a file name as parameter, the formatting can be hardcoded of course.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.